# how to initState and get data from where firebase

Tags: flutter, dart

i try to create many account and create blog and every account see blog that post by itself. how to init state `where` in firebase. I declare variable `uid` in class and get it from initstate and how to use `where` in firebase i try to mix it with streambuilder

i declare uid in class and get data by this

```
void inputData() {
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    setState(() {
      uid = user!.uid;
      // print('uid =======> $uid');
    });
  }
```

my initstate

```
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    inputData();  }
```

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> animals = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('animal')
      .orderBy('createdate')
      // .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
      .snapshots();
```

after i use `where` here .I got error

> The instance member 'uid' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: animals,
            builder: (
              BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
            ) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Something Went Wrong!');
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text('Loading');
              }

              final data = snapshot.requireData;

              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 65),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: data.size,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    });
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        '${data.docs[index]['animalName']}',
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        '${data.docs[index]['animalDetail']}',
                      ),
                      onLongPress: () async {
                        await processDeleteContent(context, data, index);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

anyway to use `where` in streambuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `uid` is set in `initState()` that calls after the class is initialized. So you get `uid` before it is set. Try to write your `animals` with `get` so it runs code written there only when you get `animals` but not on initialization:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> get animals => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('animal')
      .orderBy('createdate')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
      .snapshots();
```